# how to have a product collection with only one website and not more

Tags: magento-enterprise, websites

I want to only select products that have the website id of 1 and only 1, I don't want products that has websites ids of 1,2,3,... .

I want to select only products that are assigned to only website id 1, if I do the

```
$websiteIds=1
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds);
```

it does not show me what I want, it has products with website id 1 and other websites as well.

I think the solution is to use something like

```
addfieldtoFilter('website_ids',array('eq'=>(1)))
addfieldtoFilter('website_ids',array('neq'=>(2,3,4)))
```

however we have no such thing as website_ids, if I run this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addWebsiteFilter($websiteIds);
foreach($productCollection as $product)
{
    echo $product->getWebsiteIds();
    echo $product->getData("website_ids")
}
```

we don't have "website_ids" as an attribute that I can go and do it, so the  echo `$product->getData("website_ids")` is wrong and null, I was wondering how I can achieve this. I know that I can select all products and then get count($websiteids) and if the count was 1 and also website_id was equal to 1 I can tag the product as my selected product which I am looking, but I think it should have a better solution.

P.S, for example:

```
Product A has following websites 1,2,3
Product B has following websites 1,2,5
Product C has following websites 1
```

the program should only return C, however with the solution that I have I will have A,B,C which is not my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$storeId = 1;
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$productCollection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

If you don't know `store id` then you can grab like this:

```
$websiteId=1;
$website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId); 
foreach($website->getStoreIds() as $id){
            $storeId = $id; //we grab only one, it will be the last one if there are more than 1 stores in this website.
            exit;
    }
```

OR

```
$storeIds = $website->getStoreIds();
$storeId = $storeIds[0]; //it grabs first one
```

Hope this helps. [Ref](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86229/problem-with-addwebsitefilter-and-addstorefilter#answer-86236)

Comment: so you are saying if I filter by store id, it will be showing only one store id and not products that has store id 1 and other store ids?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: Wrong as I expected, what it does is exactly what website does, when I have web ids 1,2,3 it still shows it, but I want to just get products with one store id of 1, it still shows others.

Comment: Did yu check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86229/problem-with-addwebsitefilter-and-addstorefilter#answer-86236? I doubt your products are assigned to multiple stores.

Comment: they are assigned to multiple websites my bad

Comment: I also edited the question for clarifications.